# Android - Rounded Rectangle within Rounded Rectangle

Tags: android, rounded-corners, shapedrawable

I am currently designing a login page and I've run into a problem with using rounded rectangles. My current layout looks somewhat like this:

[image]

It's a rounded rectangle containing a smaller rounded rectangle.

As you can see, the right edges of both rectangles seem to merge. However, I want to maintain a constant distance between the borders of the two rectangles for a crisper look. Is there any way I can do this?

Comment: Is this all defined in a single drawable?

Comment: No, the outer rectangle is actually a LinearLayout that holds both a TextView and an EditText. The inner rectangle is the borders of the EditText.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the `EditText` you may want to try `layout_marginRight` in the XML.

Answer (score 1):

If your outer rect is `outerRect` and already contains the coordinates, then you can set the  bounds of the inner rect relative to the `outerRect`'s bound.

```
Rect innnerRect = new Rect(outerRect.left+5, outerRect.top+5, 
                           outerRect.right-5, outerRect.bottom-5);
```

### Update:

You can also make the image a 9-patch drawable. Define the middle of inner rect area as stretchable.

Answer (score 1):

In order to do that, the rectangles need to have the same radius on each corner.

If the corners of the outer rectangle have a 10dp radius, the inner rectangle should also have a 10dp radius.

**Edit:**

You also need to have the same padding/margins on the top, bottom and right side of the inner rectangle. Check your margins and paddings so they add up to the same value.

Comment: Yes, I have the radii set like so.